# How do I implement a WYSIWYG editor to my website?

Tags: php, html, textarea, wysiwyg

I want to quickly add a WYSIWYG editor to my website. I am not using wordpress, drupal, or joomla. I am making a website by coding it all by hand. How do I implement a WYSIWYG editor? I can not seem to find an easy straightforward way to implement one of these after I downloaded it. I particularly want to use tinyMCE because I am making a responsive website. Can somebody give me easy instructions on how to implement this and customize it to my liking?

I want to be able to implement something like this:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/classic.php

Comment: I've downvoted, as the instructions to add TinyMCE to a page are surely on that website. If you followed those instructions, please show your code, and identify where you believe you are having trouble. (This is good advice for all questions here, by the way). If you have a few minutes, do read the FAQ here - it sets out how to ask questions quite well.

Comment: Sorry but I tried for hours and the instructions on the website were quite confusing to me. I am so sorry for that! Can I possibly seek forgiveness? I do not want to be banned or anything.

Comment: Don't worry about the odd downvote `:)`. It is indeed possible to get automatically locked against asking questions here if you have a lot of downvotes and/or closed questions, but you can fix that by earning reputation by answering some questions. As I say, read the FAQ - that will help you understand what makes a good question here! Best of luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic instructions (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation)

This is the minimal configuration for getting TinyMCE to replace a textarea.

```
<!-- Place inside the <head> of your HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
 });
</script>

<!-- Place this in the body of the page content -->
<form method="post">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

And the source for the example you posted:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor"
        ],

        toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
        toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code | inserttime preview | forecolor backcolor",
        toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

        menubar: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',

        style_formats: [
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        templates: [
                {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
                {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
        ]
});</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing changed. For the installation path, do I place the tinyMCE folder download in the folder with all of my other php files? Then set the path to where it is?

Comment: If you downloaded the main package, and extracted the contents of the zip to your root web folder, the `src` path you need would be: `src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"`

Comment: I am currently not on a real server. I am on localhost using XAMPP and htdocs. I have a folder called personal website with all of my files in htdocs. I placed the folder tinymce from the download in my personal website folder. My path is currently: <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script> and it still is not working

Comment: Try changing it to `tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js`, this should match the default file/directory structure of the downloaded zip once extracted.

Comment: With your last comment I was able to get it to work now. How do I make it use those extra plugins like the example? Should I simply copy and paste your code above? I will try it and let you know.

Comment: It works now! Thank you ever so much! How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: Yep, copying and pasting that should work fine - then you can just add/remove any plugins as required. Now you have it pointing to the right folder it should all be fairly simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at TinyMCE's website, and it seems that they've put a quick install instruction right on their front page. As for which button you want to appear on your installation, they have the required information in their Documentation section. @Alfie's explanation works good enough.

And I can't stress this well enough. Read their docs, unless you want a barebone installation.